# module' object has no attribute 'SelectDateWidget'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a custom form/view in Calendarium and i keep getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SelectDateWidget'
```

CreateEvent within my forms.py

```
class CreateEvent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end', 'description', 'category', 'created_by', 'rule', 'end_recurring_period']
        widgets = {
            'start': forms.SelectDateWidget()
        }
```

EventCreateView within views.py

```
class EventCreateView(EventMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = CreateEvent
    model = Event
```

Does anyone know why i'm getting this error

Extra(If Allowed):

Within the EventCreateView its being passed "EventMixin" which looks like this

```
class EventMixin(object):
    """Mixin to handle event-related functions."""
    model = Event
    fields = '__all__'



    @method_decorator(permission_required('calendarium.add_event'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EventMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget), you can only import the `SelectDateWidget` widget from `django.forms` in Django 1.9+.

In earlier versions, you need to import it from `django.forms.extras.widgets`.

First, add the import:

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
```

Then change the `widgets` in your form to:

```
    widgets = {
        'start': SelectDateWidget(),
    }
```

Comment: This has changed in later (2.x) versions of Django. It is now `from django.forms.widgets import SelectDateWidget`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `widgets`:

```
class CreateEvent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end', 'description', 'category', 'created_by', 'rule', 'end_recurring_period']
        widgets = {
            'start': forms.widgets.SelectDateWidget()
        }
        #                    ^^
```

On another note, I suspect the file containing that snippet is named `forms.py`

Comment: While SelectDateWidget and others can be imported as forms.widgets.SelectDateWidget , the forms.SelectDateWidget import also works.

Comment: @e4c5 Definitely. I am starting to think OP has a file named `forms.py` somewhere in the current directory